# creating separate cache for different user roles

Tags: wordpress, caching, user-roles

I utilize plugins to display various prices based on the user's role. Essentially, it's akin to having different memberships or subscriptions that feature differing prices (for one particular role, all prices are free).

My aim is to employ WP Rocket or a similar plugin to cache the pages. Nonetheless, the issue at hand is that cache plugins only generate cache for guests (not logged-in users), and activating "cache for logged-in users" generates cache for each individual user. I came across a helper plugin for Rocket that produces a single cache for all logged-in users in addition to another cache for guests.

I'm curious about how to configure a cache plugin to create a separate cache for every existing or selected user role (for instance, one for Administrators and one for Customers). This would be incredibly useful for websites with many pages and users who receive varying content based on their roles.

I searched the internet for such a feature in caching plugins for wordpress and I tried to edit WP-Rocket's helper plugin called "WP Rocket | Separate Cache For Logged-in Users by Role", but I was unable to achieve my desired outcome.

Comment: Wow, this question is interesting. What was the limitation of the WP Rocket add-on? Based on title, that seems like it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: That helper plugin creates only one cache for all logged in user roles. So Customers & Editors or Other user roles cached in a single folder. it can be useful if a website has no different content for different user roles.

Comment: Hmm, that title is misleading then.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Optimize Premium does this under "Enable user per role cache"

Comment: Please elaborate. Try for [answer].